# How do I get the correct current_MODEL from devise in a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm writing an engine and I'd like it to integrate well with devise, but not necessarily be dependent on it.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to reference the current_MODEL (default: current_user).  Is there a generic method I can use in my engine's controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ryan Bigg answered my question already!

http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/engines-and-authentication/